Converting 4 way to three way
Doing some reworking of our kitchen and there is a switch we never use and would like the space for a second outlet instead. The switch being removed is a 3-way which is a part of a 4-way circuit.  The result should be a 3-way with two switches and an overhead light.  I think I have made it work by connecting the two black wires from the removed 3-way and leaving the red wire unconnected.  The 4-way switch remains connected and it seems to work in this configuration, but what is the correct way to do it?

Just because you don't use it doesn't mean you can just remove it.  Codes require switches at each entrance to a room. What's your situation?
